# SQL to get distinct records with PK

Tags: sql, distinct

Here is my table data...lets call this table TABLEX

```
ID         COL1          COL2
------------------------------
 100         a             b
 101         x             y
 102         a             b
 103         c             d
 104         e             f
 105         a             b
 106         c             d
 107         x             y
```

I want following records to be retrieved from this table

```
ID         COL1          COL2
------------------------------
 100         a             b
 101         x             y
 103         c             d
 104         e             f
```

In other words I want to retrieve distinct values from COL1 + COL2 but also show along with records' ID.

Comment: Why do you need the ID when it is not distinctly identifying the only row with that COL1/COL2 combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select min(id) as id, col1, col2
from Tablex
group by col1, col2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have observed the you return the lowest ID for every the same `col` and `col2`.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) `ID`, col1, col2
FROM tableName
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you want to select which record ID to display for a given set of values.  Your sample implies you want the lowest one.

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id, col1, col2
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY col1,cold2
  ORDER BY MIN(id)
```